# missing .NET Core Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: Visual Studio 2017]

Like you see the picture above, I don't even have Web part in the left pane of the New Project dialog box. I am trying to build an ASP.NET Core Web Application, but I cannot find .NET Core on the left pane. My visual studio 2017 version is 15.8.9 and I downloaded the Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1.403, but I still don't know how to get .NET Core. I am pretty much beginner for visual studio, so I would be very appreciate you if you can explain me step by step that I can follow. Thank you!

Comment: Follow the official HowTo: [Install Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2017). See also the Individual Components List (also reported in the Docs).

Answer (score 0):

Open the Visual Studio Installer to make changes to your installation. Select change and make sure you have the .Net Cross Platform (for .net core) box ticked and the necessary web development boxes ticked (for asp.net), then update as needed.